# Tcl: Convert an integer into binary string of arbitrary length

Tags: tcl, radix

I need a way to convert integer from decimal form to binary form. I must be possible to specify the bit length of the output bit string. If the length is more than is required for input representation then the extra bits will be padded with 0 or 1 depending on the sign of the input. If the specified bit length is too small for the input number then the procedure must generate an error.

I believe that a solution should exist with the "binary format" procedure in TCL but it has me confused. It seem that the procedure converts into hexadecimal. I am not sure if TCL can do direct conversion the way I need using built-in functions, or I will have to write a custom procedure and do it step by step.

Comment: Do you want, say 65, to become `A` or `01000001` or what?

Answer (score 4):

The [`format`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm#M22) command can express a number as binary:

```
set num 42
set width 10
puts [format "%0*b" $width $num]
# => 0000101010

set num -42
puts [format "%0*b" $width $num]
# => 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010110
```

`format` is Tcl's `sprintf`

---

`%b` was introduced in Tcl 8.6.

This code was adapted from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_digits#Tcl

```
proc num2bin {num width} {
    binary scan [binary format "I" $num] "B*" binval
    return [string range $binval end-$width end]
}

num2bin 42 10
# => 00000101010
```

Truth be told, I find binary format/scan perplexing too.

---

Another approach:

```
set num 42
set wid
set bin_digits {}

while {$num > 0} {
    lappend bin_digits [expr {$num % 2}]
    set n [expr {$num / 2}]
}
set binval [join [lreverse $bin_digits] ""]

puts [format {%0*s} $width $binval]
```

Comment: I don't why I keep getting stuck on these type of apparently trivial issues, binary, binary format, scan and I many others things all just get all mixed and confusing. Why are we using "format" here and not "binary format"?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your question: Do you want to convert a number into a string of ones and zeroes for human eyes to see? Or do you want to write binary data to a file for machines to consume? I assumed the former.

Comment: Yes it is to convert a number to a string of bits, which will be written into a file. The binary string is what I required, when input 7 becomes 111, which can we pad to get 00000111.

Comment: So although I was sure that this would work, I am actually getting this error "bad field specifier "b"", does this have something to do with the version of TCL? I have 8.5 which cannot be upgraded since it is locked in the Xilinx Vivado tool.

Comment: Yes, now it works with positive numbers. The code needs some minor typographic corrections which the forum is not allowing me to do. To make it work with negative numbers I guess I take absolute value, run the above algorithm and then if the operand was negative all along, return the 2's complement. I guess that this should be it, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a version of tcl too old to support the `%b` format, you can emulate it with a proc that looks at one bit at a time:

```
# Positive numbers only
proc num2binary {n width} {
    set bin ""
    while {$n > 0} {
        # Or set bin [string cat [expr {$n & 1}] $bin] in 8.6
        set bin "[expr {$n & 1}]$bin" 
        set n [expr {$n >> 1}]
    }
    format "%0*s" $width $bin
}

puts [num2binary 42 10]
```

This version uses bit operations and strings instead of the modulo/division and lists like Glenn's. Might be more efficient if that's a concern.

Comment: thanks, but what about negative integers?

Comment: Depends on how you want to represent them.

Comment: ok, so the negative number will be input in radix 10, then the output must be binary representation using the number of bits specified. The standard way to do this is to take absolute value of negative number, convert to binary, invert bit and add one to get 2's complement. Now I am not sure how I should implement the invert bit and add 1 on a binary string of bits in TCL. I mean its a binary string and not a number so it is not clear how to proceed with this.